# jquery progressive textbox activation

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, keyup

i have lined a number of textboxes (number not constant). using jquery i have used the each function to disable   every one of them except the first. Textboxes are given a `class = "user_inputs"` and ids are given progressively as `id="text1" , "text2"` and so on...

`$('input.user_inputs').each(function() {$(this.attr('disabled','true'});
$('input#text1').attr('disabled',false);`

what i want is - if there is a value in the first textbox only then the second box gets activated, if there is a value in second too then the third gets activated and so on. I have tried a for loop with a keyup function as below:

```
    var n=1
for(n;n<=total_textboxes;n++){
$('input#text' + n).keyup(function() {
    $('input#text' + n + 1).attr('disabled',false)
});//end keyup
}//end for
```

THis DOES NOT work - instead it hampers my page from getting loaded.

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inputs = $(".user_inputs");
for(var i = 1; i < inputs.length + 1; i++){
  var prev = $("#text" + (i - 1));
  if(prev.length){
    $("#text" + i).attr("disabled", prev.val() == '' ? true : false);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74Kzu/5/

Comment: does not work..
I think the problem here is we are not associating this code with any event.... ive tried it with keyup on #text1

Comment: sorry, i was passing strings for disabled attribute instead of booleans, edited answer, with accompanying fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an attribute, or better, the disable attribute, you have to use:

```
 $('input#text' + n + 1).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need to use `for(n;n<=total_textboxes;n++)`... `$.each()` and `$.next()` can handle it as well

As an example

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" id="text1" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" id="text2" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" id="text3" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" id="text4" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" id="text5" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" />
<input type="text" class="user_inputs" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // To demonstrate disable all first
    $('input.user_inputs').each(function() { $(this).attr('disabled','true'); });
    // Left only first one enabled
    $('input#text1').attr('disabled',false);
    // For each of your inputs
    $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        // Search for "#text + (n + 1)" blabla.. named ones
        if ($.trim(this.id).indexOf("text") >= 0) {
            // Bind keyup
            $(this).keyup(function() {
                // Again search for "#text" named ones
                if ($.trim($(this).next().attr('id')).indexOf("text") >= 0) {
                    // Enable
                    $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/nFQjH/

Comment: doesnt work after 4 textboxes . I think i can modify it to work though.

Comment: offcourse it would not work after 4 text boxes because the next box doesnt have an id that is like `text1`, `text2`. I did that on purpose to prevent including other non necessary input elements.. keep adding id's to the other inputs as `text6`, `text7` ... and it will work.